# Node.js Sequelize Erro Relacionamentos

Tags: node.js, modelo-relacional, sequelize-js

Neste relacionamento, UM Questionário pode ter MUITAS Questões, quando eu executo-o no retorno não obtenho o *ID* do `Questionário` na tabela de `Questão`, porém é criado as duas. Por que isso ocorre?

Aqui está o código que eu fiz:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('gerador', 'root', '');


var Questionario = sequelize.define('Questionario',
{

  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: null, autoIncrement:true
  },

  titulo: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,}, 

  situacao: { 
      type: Sequelize.STRING,},

  datai: { 
      type: Sequelize.DATE,},

  dataf: { 
      type: Sequelize.DATE}

},{tableName: 'Questionarios'});

var Questao = sequelize.define('Questao',{

  id:{
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: null, autoIncrement:true},

  texto:{
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  ordem:{
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,  
  },    
},{tableName: 'Questaos'});

Questao.belongsTo(Questionario, {foreignKey:'idQuestionario', as: 'Questionario'});
Questionario.hasMany(Questao, {foreignKey:'idQuestionario', as: 'Questao'});

sequelize.sync({ force: true}).then(function() {
   Questionario.create({

    titulo: 'Universidade Estacio de Sa',
    situacao: 'Ativo',
    datai: new Date(2005,1,1),
    dataf: new Date(2006,1,2)
  });
  Questao.create({

        idQuestionario:Questionario.id,
        texto: 'Qual o seu sexo?',
        ordem: 1    
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Galera, para funcionar deve-se fazer a seguinte alteração

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true}).then(function() {
   return Questionario.create({

    titulo: 'Estudos Pessoais',
    situacao: 'Ativo',
    datai: new Date(2005,1,1),
    dataf: new Date(2006,1,2)
  });}).then(function(oQuestionarioCriado) {
  return Questao.create({

        idQuestionario: oQuestionarioCriado.id,
        texto: 'Qual o seu sexo?',
        ordem: 1    
      });
  });
```

Então, a resposta dada por:

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true}).then(function() {
   return Questionario.create({

    titulo: 'Estudos Pessoais',
    situacao: 'Ativo',
    datai: new Date(2005,1,1),
    dataf: new Date(2006,1,2)
  });}).then(function(oQuestionarioCriado) {
  return Questao.create({

        idQuestionario: oQuestionarioCriado.id,
        texto: 'Qual o seu sexo?',
        ordem: 1    
      });
  });
```